# Join On Two Fields in C# Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to do this, but get the error

```
CS1941  The type of one of the expressions in the 
join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed 
in the call to 'Join'.
```

what do I need to change in my code so this works?

```
        var joinedRes = from c in currentOrders
                        join p in salesNumbers on 
new { A = c.Id, B = c.UGName } 
equals new { A = p.id, B = p.gName }
                        select new
                        {
                            c.Id,
                            c.Name,
                            c.UGName,
                            p.lQ,
                            c.Ordered
                        };
```

Comment: what type are the c.Id, c.UGName, p.id and p.gName?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli - they are all `string?`

Comment: could you should show us the classes? currentOrders and salesNumbers ?

Answer (score 0):

Feels like you have some sort of a type mismatch (unknown for sure as I write this answer).  caveat: This is totally an untested answer put of very fast as I step away...I can delete it later if I totally flubbed here
SO just cast them all (or not for those that are string? or int or whatever (kind of ugly)

```
var joinedRes = from c in currentOrders
     join p in salesNumbers on 
         new { A = (string?)c.Id, B =  (string?)c.UGName } 
         equals new { A = (string?)p.id, B =  (string?)p.gName }
     select new
     {
         c.Id,
         c.Name,
         c.UGName,
         p.lQ,
         c.Ordered
     };
```